# Tensorflow: Which graph statements are executed after the graph is built?

Tags: tensorflow

In Tensorflow, which statements within a graph definition block are executed only to build the graph vs. which are executed during training? For example:

```
with tf.Graph().as_default():
    weightsLayer1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([nInputUnits, nOutputUnits]))
    weightsLayer1 = tf.div(weightsLayer1, tf.sqrt(tf.to_float(nInputUnits)))
    biasesLayer1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([nUnitsHiddenLayer1]))
    layer1output = tf.tanh(tf.matmul(images_placeholder, weightsLayer1) + biasesLayer1)
```

Intuitively, the lines defining `weightsLayer1` and `biasesLayer1` I assume are only executed once at startup, since they initialize weights and biases. However, the line computing `layer1output` I assume executes at every training step, since `layer1output` is used downstream to compute loss, which is minimized by the optimizer. So, how does Tensorflow know, during training, to only execute the last line and not the previous ones (which would re-initialize the weights and biases)?

Comment: From my understanding all your statements above are used to build the graph and during training only the paths leading to the train op is executed. Initialization happens only once - this means your second statement tf.div is executed at train time as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You as the user are actually *telling* tensorflow which operations to run. During training, you typically tell tensorflow to execute operations that are provided by an optimizer. This looks something like this:

```
opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
train_step = opt.minimize(loss) #
for i in range(100):
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict=...)
```

Calling `opt.minimize` adds to the computation graphs the gradients w.r.t. the trainable variables as well as operations that update the variables using the gradients. `train_step` is in fact these update operations grouped using `tf.group`. If you (the user) run `train_step`, tensorflow figures out what parts of the computation graph it needs to run in order to execute these desired operations.

Likewise, if you do something like `sess.run(fetches=loss, feed_dict=...)`, you are asking tensorflow to execute all operations in the graph that are necessary to compute `loss`.

Finally, initialization operations like the one in `weightsLayer1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([nInputUnits, nOutputUnits]))` are usually run by `sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())`.

Edit: After re-reading your question, I want to be more clear about one aspect. No operations are actually executed by the graph *definition* code you provided. Tensorflow operations are executed if and only if you start a session and request the execution of parts of your graph. As stated above, that includes the initialization operations.

Comment: Thanks. To confirm: Tensorflow will execute BOTH of the 2 lines that initialize `weightsLayer1` only once, at initiialization time (which is my intent), or will the 2nd line (`weightsLayer1 = tf.div(weightsLayer1, tf.sqrt(tf.to_float(nInputUnits)))`also be re-executed at train time?

Comment: Aha. I think the trick is that the second line, calculating `weightsLayer1`, is not part of the initial value passed to the `tf.Variable` constructor, so it will be recomputed at train time, correct?

Comment: Correct. The line ``weightsLayer1 = tf.div(weightsLayer1, tf.sqrt(tf.to_float(nInputUnits)))`` is not an initialization of the variable ``weightsLayer1``, but is computing a new tensor. You happen to call that tensor ``weightsLayer1`` as well, but that is just a name that you bind to the tensor object. The corresponding operation will be executed whenever you are running a part of the graph that requires it.